# xaml Cannot bind Command properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Datagrid inside a RowDetail. I'd like to bind a command located inside my MainViewModel.I don't know how to. I tried some solution found on the net but it does not work...

I don't know what to add inside the MouseBinding Tag...

```
<Window x:Class="ListeCommandes.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ListeCommandes.View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="900"
    DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
<Window.Resources>
    <view:TypeToBrushConverter x:Key="TypeToBrushConverter" />
    <view:StatutToBrushConverter x:Key="StatutToBrushConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="ExpandAll"  Content="++" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="30" Click="ExpandAll_OnClick"/>
        <Button Name="CollapseAll"  Content="--" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="30" Margin="0" Click="CollapseAll_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="GrdLignes" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0"
              Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Lignes}" IsReadOnly="True"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" RowHeaderWidth="25">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander Background="Lavender">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="0,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Commandes"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pièce Achat" Binding="{Binding Path=Piece}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=TypeLabel}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource TypeToBrushConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Statut" Binding="{Binding Path=StatutLabel}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Statut, Converter={StaticResource StatutToBrushConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Name="grdVBC"  RowHeaderWidth="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lignes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="????" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=grdVBC, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Acheteur" Binding="{Binding Path=Acheteur}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pièce" Binding="{Binding Path=Piece}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Binding="{Binding Path=Client}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref" Binding="{Binding Path=ArRef}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref Fourn" Binding="{Binding Path=RefFourn}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Designation" Binding="{Binding Path=Designation}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qte" Binding="{Binding Path=CmQte}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vendeur" Binding="{Binding Path=Vendeur}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    public ICommand DoubleCLick { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DoubleCLick = new Command(DoubleClickAction);
    }

    private void DoubleClickAction(object parameters)
    {
        Debug.Print("OK");
    }
```

Comment: I assume that you need to replace ??? with DoubleClick

Comment: Yes but i just found a working solution, so i'll post as answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

```
<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.DoubleCLick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=grdVBC, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```